# Get distinct values of child array as additional property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

For example we have a collection with documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "Category" : "11",
    "Type" : 1,
    "Active" : true,
    "IsValid" : null,
     .
     .
     .
     .
    "AllTags": ["Product", "Product", "Product", "Response", "Comment", "Response"]
}
```

How can we output documents exactly like these, but which will contain additional field with distinct Tags: `["Product", "Response", "Comment"]`. So resulting document will look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "Category" : "11",
    "Type" : 1,
    "Active" : true,
    "IsValid" : null,
     .
     .
     .
     .
    "AllTags": ["Product", "Product", "Product", "Response", "Comment", "Response"],
    "Tags": ["Product", "Response", "Comment"] //property calculated from AllTags
}
```

I'm trying to add stage $AddFields

```
{ "$addFields" : { "Tags" : {"$reduce": { "input": "$AllTags", initialValue: [], in: {  
        $cond: { if: { "$$this": {$nin: ["$$value"]} } , then:  { $concatArrays : ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }, else: ?  }            
    } } } } }
```

But it gives this error: `"Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$$this'"`, and I don't know what to put inside `else` of `$cond` op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/index.html) operator, filters out duplicates in its result to output an array that contain only unique entries,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      Tags: { $setUnion: "$AllTags" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M106MeHPSXL)

Comment: omg, have seen that operator in the documentation multiple times, but always thought 'set' is a verb, but not 'noun'. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: There are many benefits of this operator but they have not mentioned in documentation.

Comment: where did you get that information then? is there more advanced source of knowledge than official site in web?

Comment: i learned from other's answers..SO is a good source of knowledge, many experienced peoples are here.